# How to scan another machine on the local network for open ports when most ports are closed in one's nftables firewall?

Tags: debian, firewall, nmap, port, nftables

I have almost all ports blocked (outbound and inbound) in my nftables firewall in Debian10 - how can I still scan another machine on the same local network for open ports with nmap/zenmap?

How are people using nmap usually managing their own firewall? Is there a way to open ports for the scanning only (opening the ports only temporarily for the specific scanning-packets and their expected responses)?

Comment: I would open a particular outbound port or a modest range, and then use the *documented* -g/--source-port option for nmap.

Comment: That's helpful but not really a solution; from the documentation: "The option notably doesn't have an effect for any operations that use normal operating system sockets, including DNS requests, TCP connect scan,. version detection, and script scanning. Setting the source port also doesn't work for OS detection". It didn't have any effect on the results of my scan. Or does it matter which source-port is chosen?

Comment: I could give an answer that should work, but it requires a separate IP address. so can you use an additional IP address for the purpose of doing the scan?